# What would be the "apt-cache show" equivalent on RHEL *without* requiring sudo/su?

Tags: rhel, yum, scientific-linux

How can I query the *local* package cache of `yum` on RHEL (and derivatives) without requiring superuser privileges?

**Note:** I am not interested in running an update of the package cache up front. All I am interested in is to query what the local package cache *already* knows.

---

**Edit:** it turns out the problem wasn't the `yum` operation (`search`) itself in this case, but rather the fact that some of the files underneath `/etc/yum.repos.d/` were unreadable due to some fellow admin putting them there this way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That would be something like `yum --cacheonly list`. That (as all information querying commands) is not restricted to the superuser, special powers are only required for installation/erasing (in general, *really* modifying). See the `yum(1)` manpage, it details all the commands.

Comment: Mea culpa, it is. Found `yum -C`, too. It turns out the *actual* problem was that one of my fellow admins was so ingenious to deny read access for group and world on a few files underneath `/etc/yum.repos.d/`.

Answer (score -1):

It is like: `yum list installed 'package-name'`